How can define linear map $T$: $\mathcal P_{n-m}(\textbf F) \times \mathcal P_{m-1}(\textbf F) \to \mathcal P_{n}(\textbf F)$?
The question is from this book:Linear Algebra Done Right
Define linear map $T$: $$\mathcal P_{n-m}(\textbf F) \times \mathcal P_{m-1}(\textbf F) \to \mathcal P_{n}(\textbf F)$$ by
$$T(q,r)=sq+r$$
I think $\mathcal P_{n-m}(\textbf F) \times \mathcal P_{m-1}(\textbf F)$ should be $\mathcal P_{n-1}(\textbf F)$, because the highest degree of the product polynormial should be $n-m+m-1=n-1$. What is wrong with my thought?
Thanks


Why do you think it's $n-1$?  The degree of $sq+r$ is $\deg(s)+\deg(q) = m + n-m =n$  ($\deg(r)$ is below $\deg(s)$ so it doesn't "take away" from the degree of $sq$.)

@Randall Yes, you are right. But the book defines $s$ as $\mathcal P_{m-1}$, so $deg(s)=m-1$, isn't it?

No, what I see from your clip is $\deg(s)=m$ in the first sentence of the proof.  Are you confusing $s$ with $r$?

This is what I am confusing, $s\in \mathcal P_{m-1}$, but why $deg(s)=m$ not $m-1$?

I do not see anywhere that $s \in \mathcal{P}_{m-1}$.  The author writes "let $m=\deg(s)$."

I just don't know why $\mathcal P_{n-m}(\textbf F) \times \mathcal P_{m-1}(\textbf F) \to \mathcal P_{n}(\textbf F)$ is injective?

Well, that is a different question.

@Dan Li, as written in the proof, it's because the kernel of $T$ is trivial. It's basic result from linear algebra that linear map is injective if and only if its kernel is trivial.

@Ennar Yes, I know, but the highest degree of $\mathcal P_{n−m}(F)×\mathcal P_{m−1}(F)$ is $n-1$, right?

But it times $s$ on the right. Like $x^2\mathbb{P}_{n-m}(F)$, it is not just $n-m$, but $n-m+2$.

@Bowei Tang you mean $deg(\mathcal P_{m-1}(F))=m$? why?

If $T(q,r)=rq$ or something like $ r+q$ then your claim is true. But here is $sq+r$. You cannot just add the dimension, but calculate what is the degree of $sq+r$ on the right-hand side

Ok, I see. Thanks

Here $\deg q=n-m$ and $\deg s=m$. Since in a field, there are no zero divisors, we have $\deg (sq)=\deg(s)+\deg(q)=m+n-m=n$. Also, $\deg(r)\leq m-1$.
Thus, $\deg(sq+r)=n.$
$\textbf{Edit}:$ The degree of $s$ has been fixed ($\deg=m$) and $m>0.$
If there exists nonzero polynomials $q_1,r_1$ such that $sq_1+r_1=0$, then $\deg(sq_1)=\deg(r_1) (i.e. \deg(r_1)\geq m$ since the degree of $s$ is $m$), it is impossible.

I know this, but I don't know why $\mathcal P_{n-m}(\textbf F) \times \mathcal P_{m-1}(\textbf F) \to \mathcal P_{n}(\textbf F)$ can be injective.

@DanLi See the edit.

$deg(\mathcal P_{n-m} \times \mathcal P_{m-1}) =n-1$, right?

@DanLi Right, but they are different things. You should care about what's on the right-hand side. For example, I define a map $T$ by sending $p(x)$ to $xp(x)$, but it is not from $P_{n}\to P_n$, but $P_n \to P_{n+1}.$

@DanLi Note that linear map $T:V\to W $ does not ensure that $\dim V=\dim W.$

Okay, I see, thanks

Degree of a vector space makes no sense.

@Randall Thank you. Right, should be dimension.
